# Package amsmath: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;\n(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'

Tags: align, amsmath

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{indentfirst}



\title{Test}
\author{Nguyen Van Manh \\ HE170552}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Ex1}

\textbf{A1}
The augmented matrix of the system:
\[\left[\begin{alignat*}
    1&2&-2&7\\
    -2&1&-1&1\\
    0&3&a&b
\end{alignat*}\right]\]
\[\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix}[cc|c]
    1&2&3\\
    2&-9&17
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

I get error: Package amsmath: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;\n(amsmath) trying to recover with `aligned'.

What is cause of it? How to fix it?

I was tried:

```
\[\left[\begin{alignedat}{4}
    &1&&2&&-2&&7\\
    &-2&&1&&-1&&1\\
    &0&&3&&a&&b
\end{alignedat}\right]\tag{1}\]
```

I don't get the above error at the moment but it looks like it didn't align

Comment: It isn't that obvious to me how it's supposed to look, but maybe use the `aligned` environment rather than `alignat*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line

```
\[\left[\begin{alignat*}
```

both `\[` and `\begin{alignat*}` initiate standalone display-math mode. That can't go well; hence the error message.

I think what you need to do is replace `\begin{alignat*}` with `\begin{array}{rrrr}` and, a few lines down, replace `\end{alignat*}` with `\end{array}`.

In view of the fact that you've redefined the low-level `\env@matrix` macro, you could also replace `\left[\begin{alignat*}` and `\end{alignat*}\right]` with `\begin{bmatrix}[rrrr]` and `\end{bmatrix}`, respectively.

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's claim that

```
\[\left[\begin{alignedat}{4}
    &1&&2&&-2&&7\\
    &-2&&1&&-1&&1\\
    &0&&3&&a&&b
\end{alignedat}\right]\tag{1}\]
```

should "work". It doesn't -- the alignment of the columns is poor. What *would* work is

```
\[\left[\begin{alignedat}{5}
    1&\quad&&2&\quad&&-2&\quad&&7\\
    -2&&&1&&&-1&&&1\\
    0&&&3&&&a&&&b
\end{alignedat}\right]\tag{1}\]
```

However, I don't think that anyone should prefer this to

```
\[\begin{bmatrix}[rrrr]
    1&2&-2&7\\
    -2&1&-1&1\\
    0&3&a&b
\end{bmatrix}\]
```

i.e., the solution I have earlier.

Comment: Thank sir, it's work. But when also tried with ```\begin{alignedat}{4}``` and it also work, however it doesn't seem align. can you explain why? I will add it to the question section.

Comment: @manh3 - I've edited my answer to answer your claim that `\begin{alignedat}{4}` "also works". In my view, it does not.